# Check if a given date is in a subset of the year (e.g. later than 6th of December)

Tags: .net, datetime

How can I find out whether a given `DateTime` is in a certain subset of the year. As an example I would like to know if today is between the 6th of December and the 2nd of January. The subset is expressed as a range of dates and might "wrap around" as in the example given.

Let's assume UTC so that daylight savings etc. are not an issue.

Is there a clean way to do this with the .NET BCL?

The date to be checked and the "end points" of the date range should be arbitrary.

Comment: Insufficient requirements.  What to do for 29 feb as start/end/check date?  And 6 dec - 2 jan is not a "range of the year". It overlaps 2 years.

Comment: @HenkHolterman this is more complicated than I thought. The two year overlapping part is intentional. Not sure what to make of the 29th, and also daylight savings.

Comment: Note that time is hard.  http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly stating dates, so I assume time is not an issue, and we can ignore daylight savings complexities et.al. In this case, you can make a simple numeric expression of the date of the year, and have a little logic for wrap-around cases. I'm not saying it's pretty, but it gets you there. For example:

```
void Main()
{
    var range = new DateRange(new DateTime(2015,12,6), new DateTime(2016,1,2));

    Console.WriteLine(range.IsDateInRange(new DateTime(2015, 12, 28)));
    Console.WriteLine(range.IsDateInRange(new DateTime(2015,  1,  1)));
    Console.WriteLine(range.IsDateInRange(new DateTime(2015,  1,  3)));
    Console.WriteLine(range.IsDateInRange(new DateTime(2015, 11, 28)));
}

public class DateRange
{
    public const int OneYearWrap = 1200;
    public int BeginValue { get; private set; }
    public int EndValue { get; private set; }

    public DateRange(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
    {
        BeginValue = DateValue(begin);
        EndValue = DateValue(end);
        if (EndValue < BeginValue) 
            EndValue += OneYearWrap;
    }

    public bool IsDateInRange(DateTime date)
    {
        int dateValue = DateValue(date);
        if (EndValue > OneYearWrap && dateValue < BeginValue)
            dateValue += OneYearWrap;
        return dateValue >= BeginValue && dateValue <= EndValue;
    }

    int DateValue(DateTime date)
    {
        return date.Month * 100 + date.Day;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison operators are overloaded for `DateTime`. Why not use something like:

```
DateTime x = ...
if (x > new DateTime(2015, 12, 6)) {
    // ... do whatever ...
}
```

and leave the dirty details to the implementors (i.e. BCL).

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I don't understand what should be inelegant/illegible about using comparison operators...?

Comment: As I understood the question, it goes for expressing a generic range of dates over any year, not specific dates. E.g. the year should be left out of the comparison, which the default operator (luckily) does not do.

Comment: I was trying to reflect the title of this question and to point out that there are comparison operators. If years are out of the picture, it's going to be hard as the comments on the question show. My bet is that the requirements/specifications of this task are not understood yet.

Comment: @Dejan what's not understood? Can you point to an input where the output is unclear? Except maybe the Feb. 29th issue which I don't care much about. Let's use UTC and that is solved.